Can I start a sidekiq job from a Heroku procfile?
If I have a worker called MigrationWorker can I run that from a procFile that would run when pushing code to Heroku?
This is my current procFile that starts everything, but I wonder if I can either run it from a rake task or just somehow run the worker itself?
release: bin/rails db:migrate
web: bin/start-pgbouncer-stunnel bundle exec puma -p ${PORT:-3000}
worker: bundle exec sidekiq -c ${SIDEKIQ_CONCURRENCY:-5}


Beside my answer I see there is an event specifically run on startup : https://github.com/sidekiq/sidekiq/wiki/Deployment#events It is probably a better solution than spawning a service

You can create a file at the root of your app and add the code that triggers the Sidekiq job:
custom_file.rb
MyWorker.perform_async

And in your procfile you can create a service which does:
sidekiq_job_at_boot: rails runner custom_file.rb

Not sure if best solution.
Maybe some gotchas and someone may have a better solution. But it should work.

Yes, You can start Sidekiq job using your current procFile. It'll automatically start the Sidqkiq when you push your procFile.
And another way is to add only configuration in your procFile by adding
worker: bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml

And you can confirm that and scale it by calling below command to your terminal or on Heroku console and get idea it's working or not.
heroku ps:scale worker=1

You can check the logs to ensure that the worker is running correctly by running
heroku logs --tail --ps worker

